# ASP .NET Core builds project on every item add, how to disable

Tags: asp.net-core

I have hard times on migrating one of our enterprise MVC projects to Core 2.1.

I want to move the project to the new structure Razor Pages + View Components from Controllers + Views/Partials. We have a ton of models and components and actions there.

When I convert projects I usually move things around, copy items to new paths, run automated refactorings, create new/change classes to fit the new requirements and design and that BREAKS the project. A build is the last thing I do when everything is already setup, just to see if I missed something.

Now after few refactorings and breaking changes I can't add new items(razor pages, view components and so on) just because project is not buildable.

"There was an error running the selected code generator: Failed to build project..."

Basically it forces me to do everyting manually, check every copied/migrated piece of code just to add a new item !

I'm in nightmare, please someone wake me up, how to disable this thing ? or suggest a migration strategy for large projects.

Answer (score 1):

First, and most importantly, adding a item via scaffolding will *always* kick off a project build. The scaffolding needs the project to be in a consistent state in order to function correctly. There is no way around this.

Aside from that, Visual Studio will only rebuild on changes if you're actually running the site. So if you've got it running in IIS Express, kill it to avoid that.

For what it's worth, it's better to correct errors as you go, anyways. It much easier to process a few errors at a time than hundreds all at once, and you'll also then be able to take advantage of Visual Studio's refactoring features, which only work when the project can build, making the total amount of work you have to do usually far less.

Comment: Because there's model references, context references, etc. You can just manually add a `*.cshtml` and accompanying `*.cshtml.cs` file, without kicking off builds, but if you want to *scaffold* it, you're out of luck.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, however I don't see any difference between generating a Razor Page and an ASPX (old web forms) page, which both result in view and code behind files. Why adding a View/RP in Core requires rebuild ? Also when you develop or refactor/convert something you follow a particular flow like 'first I'm doing this, add this, modify there and so on which results in buildable code'. The feature not only breakes the flow (forcing you to switch from what are you doing/planning to keep your code buildable first) but its actually blocking in certain situations.

Comment: I don't agree, and it's pretty much entirely a waste of your time complaining about it to me. If anything, take it to the ASP.NET Core team on the Github project, but I don't see it changing. As it stands, you're just going to have to suck it up and deal, because that's just the way it is.

Comment: You could add `<MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>false</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>` to your project file to exclude your views from being compiled when building.

Answer (score 0):

in **MVC**:

- Add -> View adds scaffold without build

in **Core**:

- Add -> View adds scaffold + build
- Add -> New Item -> View adds without build

So if you don't want to run build on every single add in **Core** use

Add -> New Item -> ...